# Exception when no consumers set in Reactive messaging in Quarkus

Tags: amqp, quarkus, activemq-artemis, smallrye-reactive-messaging

I followed the official Quarkus messaging guide and create a simple example to taste the Reactive messaging feature using AMQP(Apache Artemis).

The complete code is [here](https://github.com/hantsy/quarkus-sample/tree/master/amqp).

The example is working but a small issue there, I have to start a `curl` to consume the message firstly, then use another `curl` to send messages.

```sh
// start consumer side.
curl http://localhost:8080/messages -H "Accept:text/event-stream"

// start sending.
curl http://localhost:8080/messages -d "Hello, Quarkus" -H "Content-Type:text/plain"

// then the consumer exit.
// and sending a message will cause an exception.
```

If cancel the consumer, and then sending messages, there is an exception thrown.

```sh
2020-10-12 20:18:54,137 WARN  [io.net.cha.AbstractChannelHandlerContext] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-6) Failed to mark a promise as failure because it has failed already: DefaultChannelPromise@4bda4836(failure: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException), unnotified cause: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.newClosedChannelException(AbstractChannel.java:957)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.write(AbstractChannel.java:865)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.write(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1367)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:717)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWriteAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:764)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:790)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:758)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWriteAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:767)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:790)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:758)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWriteAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:767)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:790)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:758)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWriteAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:767)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:790)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:758)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.ConnectionBase.write(ConnectionBase.java:124)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.ConnectionBase.lambda$queueForWrite$2(ConnectionBase.java:215)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
: io.netty.util.IllegalReferenceCountException: refCnt: 0, decrement: 1
    at io.netty.util.internal.ReferenceCountUpdater.toLiveRealRefCnt(ReferenceCountUpdater.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ReferenceCountUpdater.release(ReferenceCountUpdater.java:138)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.release(AbstractReferenceCountedByteBuf.java:100)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.DefaultHttpContent.release(DefaultHttpContent.java:92)
    at io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil.release(ReferenceCountUtil.java:88)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.write(AbstractChannel.java:867)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.write(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1367)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWrite0(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:717)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWriteAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:764)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:790)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:758)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWriteAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:767)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:790)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:758)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWriteAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:767)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:790)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:758)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeWriteAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:767)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.write(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:790)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.writeAndFlush(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:758)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.ConnectionBase.write(ConnectionBase.java:124)
    at io.vertx.core.net.impl.ConnectionBase.lambda$queueForWrite$2(ConnectionBase.java:215)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:500)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

If it is possible to cache the messages in Apache Artemis even there is no consumer connected.

Comment: How long would you cache the messages? You may have an out of memory before the first consumer connect.

Comment: BTW, I don't get an exception. I just don't get any message sent before the connection of the consumer.

Comment: I have just cloned your repository and executed `./mvnw compile quarkus:dev` followed by `curl -d "Hello World" -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -X POST http://0.0.0.0:8080/messages` and `curl http://0.0.0.0:8080/messages` and I can't reproduce the issue. I would create a new ActiveMQ Artemis instance using the command `./bin/artemis create` from your artemis home.

Comment: @DomenicoFrancescoBruscino updated the content and detailed steps. BTW, I am using docker to bootstrap an Artemis server.

Comment: Does the message generated by AOT artefact ( native image ) ?

Comment: @Ben I was using jvm at that moment.

Answer (score 0):

Apache ActiveMQ Artemis has a powerful and flexible [addressing model](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/address-model.html). If your scenario is a Point-to-point messaging you could define your address customizing the broker configuration, ie:

```
<address name="messages">
    <anycast>
        <queue name="messages" />
    </anycast>
</address>
```

The broker will create at startup all addresses and queues defined in the configuration, so when the sender will send a message it will be routed to an existent queue.